# Keep checking for a text in a file until its found or a certain timeout

Tags: java, loops

I need to check for a error log file for certain time after starting a process. Either the word found or the timeout reached, I need to exit informing the text is found or Text is not found until the timeout. I tried like below but couldnt achieve

```
public void waitFortext(String expectedText,
    String filePath){
    long timeout = 50000 + System.currentTimeMillis();
    File file = new File(filePath);
    String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "UTF-8");
    boolean available = false;
    while (available || System.currentTimeMillis() > timeout) {
        available = content.contains(expectedText);
        Thread.sleep(500);
        if (available) {
            return;
        }
    }
}`
```

Comment: Would you not want the while loop to be `(!available || System.currentTimeMillis() < timeout)`? So that it carries on until the file is found?

Answer (score 0):

Make a variable `oldTime` and set it to `System.nanoTime` when you want the time to start. Make a variable `newTime` and update it to `System.nanoTime` in every time the code loops. Compare the difference of these two values to your wanted amount of time, exiting the loop when the difference is greater.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you read file only once.

Move line

```
String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "UTF-8");
```

inside loop (make it first statement.